# how to add a box over card view on selection?

Tags: java, android, list, layout

I have a list of hours created with card view and recycler view. I want to show the changes on some selection of hours. on selection I want to show type of blue box in image. How can I achieve it??
I think I need to add multiple layouts in the parent layout and change the background color of the layouts. Is it a right way?? Or is it possible with any other way???

[image]

card layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:background="@drawable/lineh"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/txthour"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Main Layout

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id = "@+id/toolbar_container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_contentframe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment Layout

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.List"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1.40"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a custom view(or layout that is, obviously, also a view) for this purpose. What you need to do is override onDraw method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawOverlay(canvas);
}
```

In this case you need to setup all overlay params for your view and after that just draw on canvas a selection. Here is a [good article](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) about it.